# How to get more than one model data in Spring Controller

Tags: spring-boot

I'm a spring newbie.
I'm doing this spring-boot project where I have 2 tables for users viz user and user_details. I've made 2 models corresponding to the tables.

When the client fills up the user form, the data for both the user model and user_details model are coming from a same stream. In such a case, how do I handle 2 data models in the controller?

A case for getting a single model object, the controller function would be:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value= "/user")
public void add(@RequestBody User user)  {
// do stuffs on model
   }
```

How do we address the issue if two models' data are arriving in that post request?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MultiValueMap, something like below ,replace string with your custom objects.
//Create a multimap to hold the named parameters 
MultiValueMap parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap(); parameters.add("userName", marshalRequest(userNameObj)); parameters.add("password", marshalRequest(passwordObj)); 
// Create the http entity for the request HttpEntity> entity = new HttpEntity>(parameters, headers);

Comment: LNP can you  do a more elaborate example demonstration please